# Пустой app.js после npm run dev в laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, frontend, npm

app.js остается путсым после запуска команды npm run dev

Comment: Речь про ```/public/js/app.js``` ? А в ```/resources/js/app.js``` есть контент ?

Comment: да, и контент есть.

Comment: Можно было еще короче написать свой вопрос

Comment: Очевидно, что некорректно указаны директории – пустота компилируется прежде всего из пустоты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто убрал в web файлике последний mix.js.